# AngularJS custom Filter based on data rating (Positive/Negative);

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm trying to create custom `filter` for my `scope` data, and i have `JSON` file with rating inside, from the drop down you can select would you like to see positive or negative rating or all together which is default behavior. Now i load my data into `JSON`. I don't know how to pass data and update the view

*js* file:

```
var self = this;
self.data = [{"subject":"math","grade":1},
  {"subject":"chemistry","grade":-1},
  {"subject":"gym","grade":0.8},
  {"subject":"music","grade":-0.8}]   

 self.rating = function(){
  }
```

*HTML*

```
 <select name="grade" id="" ng-model="rating" >
                    <option value="all">all</option>
                    <option value="positive">positive</option>
                    <option value="negative">negative</option>
                </select>
                    <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="opt in self.data  | orderBy:'grade' |     
                 filter:self.rating"">
                    {{opt.subject +" " + opt.grade}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: You can create a custom filter an do such a handle filtering https://plnkr.co/edit/hEUl5YbvHeV4Auew9adO?p=preview

Comment: Okey since I'm pretty new to this why it doesn't show all?

Comment: because `selft.rating` was defined as function, now [check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hEUl5YbvHeV4Auew9adO?p=preview), it should work